# How update dinamically content of modal after an update?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of messages displayed through a datatable linked to a database. For the operation of modifying a line of my datatable I use modals and when I modify a line of my datatable, the database is updated as my database but not my modal. The modal is updated only if I refresh the page. Would it be possible to update the modal dynamically after modification to the closing of the modal ?

I manage to display my modal and modify my database as well as my datatable dynamically with ajax. I tried to modify the contents of the modal with a refresh.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI487.png), [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VArkV.png), [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUEJ2.png), [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax011.png), [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O7zp.png)

```
@Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Nouvelle", null, FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)" }))

<div class="form-group">

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.message, "Titre", new { @class = "control-label" })

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.titre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.titre)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.message, "Message", new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.message, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: 150px; max-width: 100%" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.message)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.auteur, "Auteur", new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.auteur, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.auteur)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date_publication, "Dernière date de publication", new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date_publication, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date_publication)
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Retour</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok">Modifier</button>
</div>
```

}

×
                 Modification

```
  var PopupForm = function (id) {
        var url = "/Nouvelle/EditId?id=" + id;

        $("#modificationContent").load(url, function () {
            $("#modification").modal("show");
        })
    }

    function SubmitForm(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Nouvelle/Edit",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $("#modification").modal("hide");
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    toastr.success("Votre news a bien été modifiée !");
                } else {
                    toastr.error("Les champs titre et/ou message(s) doive(nt) être rempli(s) !");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

[HttpPost]//controller
    public ActionResult Edit(News tempNews)
    {
        if (tempNews.titre != null && tempNews.message != null)
        {
            string test = tempNews.titre.Trim();
            if (tempNews.titre.Trim() != "" && tempNews.message.Trim() != "")
            {
                using (PortailEntities db = new PortailEntities())
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid && tempNews != null)
                    {
                        var v = db.News.Where(n => n.id_news == tempNews.id_news).FirstOrDefault();

                        v.titre = tempNews.titre.Trim();
                        v.message = tempNews.message.Trim();
                        v.auteur = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
                        v.date_publication = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
        }
        return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I would like to update the modal dynamically as the datatable.

Comment: `I use modals and when I modify a line of my datatable, the database is updated as my database but not my modal. The modal is updated only if I refresh the page.`  this is not clear? inside the modal there is update form, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry if isn't clear. I retrieve the data from my line in the modal that I load in a partial view. After updating, the modal needs to be refreshed, that's my problem.

Comment: <div class="modal fade" id="modification" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header-edit">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Modification</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" id="modificationContent">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: It's my main modal where I call partial view

Comment: Yes it must be refresh

Comment: Okay! What you mean refresh here?

Comment: I think if the update is successful then modal should be closed and datatable should be updated, isn't it?

Comment: Yes indeed, but not the modal if i click on my button "modifier" in my datatable.

Comment: Why you don't want to close the modal?

Comment: Once modified the modal closes and the datatable gets updated. But if I click again on the button to modify my databtable the data are not updated, the modal displays the old data.

Comment: I just noticed that when I delete temporary files and cookies my modal is updated.